# can not get cUrl response to .ajax() for redirect

Tags: php, json, ajax, curl

I have a php cURL request which is run when .ajax() is run on form submit:

```
    // A sample PHP Script to POST data using cURL
    $headers = array(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization',
        'x-api-key: xxxxx',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    );
    $post_data = '{
        "user_email": "'.stripslashes($_POST['email']).'",
        "user_firstname": "'.stripslashes($_POST['personName']).'",
    }';
        
   // Prepare new cURL resource
    $crl = curl_init('https://api.examplesite.com/api/site');
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);   
    // Set HTTP Header for POST request 
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        
    // Submit the POST request
    $result = curl_exec($crl);
    if(curl_exec($crl) === false) {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($crl);                  
     } else {
       $output = json_decode($result, true);
       echo json_encode($output);
      }
    // close the request
    curl_close($crl);
```

And here's the .ajax() post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: location.href,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        ajaxRequest: 1,
        sendDemoEmail: sendDemoEmail,
        email: email.val(),
        personName: name.length != 0 ? name.val() : 'no_name',
    },
    success: function (data) { // CANT RETRIEVE SUCCESS
        console.log('yes result', data);
        $('#result').html(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {  // RUNS ERROR
        console.log('no result', data); 
        $('#result').html(data); // EMPTY
},
```

The result from cUrl is as follows:

```
{"errors":[],"messages":[],"site_url":"https:\/\/www.site.com\/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ2ZXJpZmljYXRpb25fY29kZSI6IiQyeSQxMCQzWXQwWlE1d0FGd0ZWaHNFdnZwdm0uQnl4WVNyS29EejlKVTZEQ0xzNnBtUFd1VFA2MFwvSE8iLCJuZXdfdHJpYWxfZ"}
```

User flow:

- submit form with email with .ajax() POST
- send data with cUrl to API
- retrieve data from API response in cUrl json_decode
- use the cUrl API response in my .ajax() POST to redirect to the site_url in the reponse.

**I am unable to get a success from the .ajax() POST (it return error) and also unable to also access the site_url in the .ajax() for a redirect after a success. What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: What does "unable to" mean specifically? Do you get an error - either from cURL or from JavaScript? What response do you see to the AJAX request if you look in the browser's developer tools? Have you done any basic investigation at all?

Comment: @ADyson as specified cUrl is success and outputs the following result above, ajax runs as error with the specified code on document load - why this is so, I can not understand

Comment: `ajax runs as error with the specified code`...what error, exactly? Did you check the console and network tools in the browser, as I mentioned?

Comment: the .ajax() returns as error state, in the data object is the echoed response from cUrl  and followed by the website's html for some reason. I am unable to get the .ajax() as a success. How could i retrieve the $output from cUrl to my .ajax() as success?

Comment: `as error state`...yes you already said that. But there will be a _specific error message_ which tells you what's wrong. That's what we need to know. And, as per https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ the signature of the "error" callback is `Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )` - you're only handling one of those three parameters in your version, so you're not looking at all the info. And also you still haven't reported back from the browser's Developer Tools - do you understand what I mean when I say that? I can't keep asking repeatedly for the same information.

Comment: I am getting a response status code 200 OK with the error. It seems likely that its some kind of a json formatting issue in some phase (when I remove the dataType: json from my JS part I'm getting a success which outputs the cUrl response JSON + whole website HTML in the console).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236093/discussion-between-user3615851-and-adyson).

Comment: `It seems likely that its some kind of a json formatting issue`... so then, one more time: please **check the browser's Console for an error message**. If jquery fails to parse the JSON it will put an error in the console.

Comment: `I'm getting a success which outputs the cUrl response JSON + whole website HTML in the console`...well there's your mistake then. You need to make sure it only outputs the JSON in response to the AJAX request. HTML+JSON is not valid JSON.

Comment: but in my PHP cUrl response I can see only the response from API which is JSON, how could I stop this HTML from being included in my JSON when retrieving it in the JS?

Comment: `but in my PHP cUrl response I can see only the response from API which is JSON`...yes because that's what comes back from curl ONLY. But presumably _your_ PHP script outputs some HTML before and/or after the section of code which you've shown us.

Comment: So either a) you need some judicious use of `if` statements to ensure that when the AJAX call comes in it goes straight to the section you've shown without running any other code, and stops after it's output the JSON, or b) you need to move the PHP which responds to the AJAX request to a separate file so it doesn't output anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Needed to add a exit(); to the PHP cUrl after the curl_close so my JSON response would not include site HTML

```
// close the request
curl_close($crl); 
exit();
```